# remove multiple html tags using javascript in array items

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items

```
 headers = ['E-mail', 'Phone', 'Phone 1\r']
```

there are multiple tags i want to remove all the tags

i tried this

```
headers = lines[0].split(",");
headers.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
  arrayItem.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
});
```

but this is not removing tags. There can be other tags also which i want to remove

Any solution Thanks

Comment: what tags u wanna remove ? all the html tags?

Comment: @norbekoff `<br/> <\r> <\n>` generally these tags i want to remove

Comment: `</r>` and `</n>` are not html tags

Comment: What is `lines`?

Answer (score 0):

The [replace method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a value; it doesn't change the string you supplied as a parameter "in place".  You need to save that return value somehow; right now you're just discarding it.  One example:

```
headers = ['E-mail', 'Phone', 'Phone 1\r'] 
headers = headers.map(s => s.replace(/\n|\r/gm, ''));
// headers is now ['E-mail', 'Phone', 'Phone 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let headers = ["E-mail", "Phone", "Phone 1\r", "<h1> hello world </h1/>"];
headers.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
  const example = arrayItem.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
  console.log(example);
  // expect out
  /*
  E-mail
  Phone
  Phone 1
  hello world
  */
});
```

[Referencie replace](https://geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-strip-out-html-tags-from-a-string-using-javascript/#:%7E:text=To%20strip%20out%20all%20the,innerText%20property%20from%20HTML%20DOM.)